# Rails 5 Carrierwave - Strong Param exists but nil in hash

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I have applications table with attachment field which is a file uploaded by carrierwave. I'm using SQLLite. Upon application form submit, in #create

@application = Application.new(application_params)

@application contains attachment as nil.
Interestingly,
params[:attachment] is  nil also but params[:application][:attachment] = 'valid/path/of/file' and application_params is also 'same/valid/path/of/file'.

As a result @application cannot be saved as I cannot save without attachment. It has suddenly started and I cannot figure out. Can anyone please advise. TIA. #create action upto save:

```
def create
@application = Application.find_by_user_id_and_type_id(params[:application][:user_id], params[:application][:type_id])
if params[:application][:attachment].nil? || params[:application][:attachment].blank?
  flash[:notice] = "You have to add an attachment of type - .doc/.docx/.pdf/.txt/.rtf."
end

if @application.nil?
  @application = Application.new(application_params)

  if @application.save
```

Here's the browser output from submit.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"egFav9RYAOXJQ==","application{"user_=>"109", "type_id"=>"4", "years_of_experience"=>"", "attachment"=>"/uploads/data_attachment/attachment/93/Steps_to_be_done.docx", "message"=>""},"commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Now a little hack I did today morning that 'forced' it to work for sometime.Not sure, why it worked then and not now.

```
def application_params
params.require(:application).permit(:user_id, :type_id, :message, :years_of_experience, :attachment)
if params[:attachment].nil?
  params.fetch(:application).permit(:user_id, :type_id, :message, :years_of_experience, :attachment)
end
```

Comment: Have the same issue. Haven't found a solution yet, and the little hack didn't work for me.